# Roulette variance

Tags: probability

In doing a probability question that asked for the variance of the payout of a single "$A$" bet on a single number vs the variance of the payout of "A" successive $1 bets on a single number,  I got two different answers. The latter type of bet was smaller by a factor of "A". Intuitively how does this make sense?

A wager of "A" returns winnings of "35A" with probability 1/37 and a loss of $A otherwise. The two variances I got were 46656/1369*B^2 and 46656/1369*B.

Comment: Please show what two answers you got.

Comment: Sorry... I added that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance is the probability-weighted sum of *squared* distances from the expected value.  The squaring gives "disproportionate" weights to large distances, e.g.:

When you double your bet size, your profit/loss in both the win or loose scenario doubles.  The probabilities to win or loose stay unchanged.  Hence your expected gain/loss doubles, and the distance between gain/loss to expected gain/loss doubles as well in both the "win" and the "lose" case.

But the squared distances quadruple.

So your probability-weighted sum of squared distances, i.e. your variance, quadruples as well.

This holds obviously in general, i.e. for other factors than $2$: if you multiply your bet size by $A$, your variance increases from $\sigma^2$ to $A^2\cdot \sigma^2$.

Now what happens when instead of doubling, you repeat the original bet twice. 
As the bets are independent of each other, your total result is a sum of independent variables.

You have four scenarios: win\win, loose\loose, win\loose and loose\win.

The expected value of the total is the same as when doubling the bet (you can see this when you write out the probability-weighted sum of the four scenarios).

But the largest distance from expected value, the one in the win\win case, has now a smaller probability.  You have two new distances, with the win\loose and the loose\win case, but the squared values of these are ("disproportionately") smaller than the squared distance of the larger one which has now a much lower weight.

That the total variance in general here is $A\sigma^2$ is a well known property of the variance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29), and you can find a proof here: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~jhoey/papers/Hoey_SampleSize2010.pdf but a simple intuitive derivation - I have to pass on that one...

Nevertheless, what you end up with is that in the first case you have $A^2\sigma^2$ vs. $A\sigma^2$ in the second case - so there's the factor $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to place a total of $A$ dollars on bets on
the wheel. 
Intuitively, 
by spreading out your $A$ dollars over $A$ separate spins of the wheel
rather than betting the entire $A$ dollars on one spin,
you take *less risk* (if $A>1$).
This is an example of the saying, "Don't put all your eggs in one basket."

In particular, the chance that you will lose all $A$ of the smaller bets is
less than the chance you will lose a single large bet.

Variance is a measure of risk, so it is smaller in the less risky case.